# Find distribution $f(t)$ given integral equation $\int_0 ^\infty e^{-u} f(t-u) du = H(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, distribution-theory

Find a distribution function$f(t)$ that solves the integral solution $$\int_0 ^\infty e^{-u} f(t-u) du = H(t)$$
for $-\infty < t<\infty$ and $t\neq 0$. $H(t)$ is Heaviside step function.

How to solve this? I have no idea. I think here distribution means general solutions.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Laplace transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform)?

Answer (score 1):

Distributions means topological dual of the $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c$ functions. This allows for very general solutions (as Dirac masses for instance). (In this case however, the expression is ill-defined for some distributions...)

In this case, there is a solution following these steps :

1. change the variable in the integral, so that $f$ does not depend on $t$ anymore in the integrand
2. differentiate the equality with respect to $t$
3. find $f$

I find :
$f(t) = \delta(t) + H(t)$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac mass (at $0$).

You can check indeed that if $t < 0$ :

$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-u} (\delta(t-u) + H(t-u)) du = 0 = H(t)$

and if $t > 0$ :

$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-u} (\delta(t-u) + H(t-u)) du = e^{-t} + (1 - e^{-t}) = 1 
= H(t)$

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate both sides of the given equation
$$H(t)=\int_0 ^\infty e^{-u} f(t-u) du$$
with respect to $t$
\begin{align}
H’(t)=&\int_0 ^\infty e^{-u} \frac{d}{dt}f(t-u) du
=- \int_0 ^\infty e^{-u} \frac{d}{du}f(t-u) du \\
\overset{ibp}=&\>-e^{-u} f(t-u) \bigg|_0^\infty
-\int_0 ^\infty e^{-u} f(t-u) du
=f(t)-H(t)
\end{align}
Thus
$$f(t) = H’(t)+H(t)=\delta(t)+H(t)$$